# Prisma - How to order Users by the amount of Posts (orderBy and _count)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, prisma

I found this query in the docs:
It says "sort by the count of related records." which is exactly what I want.

```
const getActiveUsers = await prisma.user.findMany({
  take: 10,
  orderBy: {
    posts: {
      _count: 'desc',
    },
  },
})
```

https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/filtering-and-sorting#sort-by-relation-aggregate-value

Eventhough it looks promising it is not working and gives me the following error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "\nInvalid `prisma.user.findMany()` invocation:\n\n{\n  orderBy: {\n    posts: {\n    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n      _count: 'desc'\n    }\n  }\n}\n\nUnknown arg `posts` in orderBy.posts for type UserOrderByInput. Available args:\n\ntype UserOrderByInput {\n  uid?: SortOrder\n  username?: SortOrder\n  pictureURL?: SortOrder\n}\n\n",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 4,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
```

Here is my Prisma schema: its a simple one-to-many relation:

```
model User {
  uid String @id @default(uuid())
  username String? @db.VarChar(24) @unique
  pictureURL String? @db.VarChar(255)
  posts Posts[] @relation
}
```

What am I missing? Do I have to use keywords like "include" or "select" to get it running?

Comment: Have you checked the note that says `Note: It is not currently possible to return the count of a relation.`? https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/filtering-and-sorting#sort-by-relation-aggregate-value

Comment: @Nelloverflow Yes and i don't want to know the count of the relation, I just want it to get sorted by the count of the relation.
Basicially what I want is that the code snipped from the docs work

Comment: What version of prisma are you running? If you are using an old version `orderByRelation` may not be available, or needed to be added to the `previewFeatures` array in the `generator` block

Comment: @Ironolife the docs say it is available from "2.19.0 and later", I was using 2.26.0.
I upgradet to 3.14.0 and it fixed it for me :)
Thank you